# how to set up multiple IP addresses on my linux?

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, ip

I'm doing some computer network homework and I'm supposed to develop some sort of Peer to Peer file sharing software, and when I wanna test it I need to run a few (5) instances on my linux/ubuntnu 11.10 .   which means each one need to has a unique IP address. I heard I can do that but I dunno how. how can I have many IP addresses on a single computer? thanks

Comment: How about five instances of VirtualBox?

Comment: I don't have enough space for running that many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about two different problems:

1. How to assign multiple IP addresses to a single machine? That is possible, that is a standard functionality of any modern operating system. And that is also off-topic on StackOverflow. In Linux the way to persistently configure it can be very distribution-specific. `ip addr add $IP_ADDRESS dev $INTERFACE` is the general way, but won't survive a reboot or network reconfiguration.
2. How to allow an application instance use a selected one of the machine addresses? That is quite easy – you must bind your server socket to an address. Usually you will only provide a port number (the IP address set to `INADDR_ANY` for the standard C IPv4 socket API), but you can use any IP address on the machine there. Details depend on the API you are using.

Answer (score 0):

We solved that by using some Virtual Machines.. Every VM has its own IP and it behaves like a standalone OS.

//Edit:

VirtualBox is my favourite: http://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: "I don't have enough space for running that many." @ePezhman
not enough diskspace?

you could try running vms on extern devices..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006102/running-virtual-machines-on-usb-stick

Answer (score 0):

If you are programming future-oriented, your program deals with IPv4 as well as IPv6. In this case, you can have several IPv6 addresses on one PC and maybe tell each instance to bind to a distinct address.